# ExpressJS: passing parameters to html doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Here is what I have in my `server.js`:

```
var browserify = require('browserify-middleware');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path    = require("path");

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Listening at http://localhost:8080');

// routes will go here
app.get('/render', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'), {text: "sfsdfsf"});
});
```

and here are the ways I tried to get the variable `text` in my `index.html`, althgouh none worked:

```
<h1>{{ text }} </h1>
<h1><% text %> </h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
var text = "<%= text %>";
var text2 = "{{ text }}";
</script>
```

Any thoughts where I am going wrong?

Comment: `res.sendFile()` does not have any template features like you are trying to use.  You need to use an actual template engine (pug, handlebars, dust, ejs, etc...) and then use `res.render()` to pass it data for use in the rendering.

Comment: I gave you four template engines, all of which have documentation for working with Express.  Please do a little homework on your own and then you can ask a more specific question if you get stuck.  Start with pug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option1: I would suggest to add template engine like pug. Template engines replace the variables in a template file with actual values. To implement pug template, visit https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Option 2:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');

var path = require("path");
var app = express();


const template = (text) => {
return `
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
    <title>sample</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <h1>${text}</h1>
   </body>
 </html>`;
}

app.get('/render', function(req, res) {
  res.send(template('Hello'));
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Listening at http://localhost:8080');
```