# Node server with express - Inject dynamic html into index.html using res.send({})

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I have a dummy node js server with express and I am exposing a dummy `Index.html` on which I have a simple form like:

```
<form action="/results" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Full Name" />
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
          <input type="file" name="picture" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit"value="picture" />
        </form>
```

When the form is submitted and I'm doing the post:

```
app.post("/results"), function (req, res, next) { }
```

instead of doing the classic res.send() :

```
res.send(`
some html with updated data 
`)
```

I just want to update/inject in `Index.html` elements dynamically without creating a new html template and add something like `Hi <span>${req.body.username}</span> <i>your profile image was updated</i>`

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass parameters to your template you have multiple options,
see this post for instance :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46722250/16956436

Comment: it is a backup idea but still a bit rudimentary , I was thinking something like adding dynamically